# How to compile a module as an AAR and include it in the project in one build?

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, aar

I have an app module and a module that I'm using as a library -- I'm still making changes to the library, so it isn't precompiled. The library module has its own res folder, which I'd like to keep separate from the main app's res folder. I believe the only way to do this is to package the library as an aar before including it in the main app. It would be convenient if I could run a single Gradle build to package the library and include it. Is this possible?

gradle.build for app (which compiles "my-library"):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.app.id"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 5
        versionName "1.4"
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            assets.srcDirs = [project.ext.ASSET_DIR]
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile project(':my-library')
}
```

gradle.build for my-library:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 25
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: My own solution is : delete the module/build/output/aar/*.aar and build the module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that Android Studio is smart enough handle a library module with a res folder. My error was coming from a conflict in the Manifest files.